# Capybara NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am currently reading Michael Hartl's Rails book, and am on chapter 3 where you begin to write tests.  My problem is, I can't get the first test to work.  From googling and reading several threads no stackoverflow, as well as the Capybara readme, I have made some changes from his code however I still cannot get the visit function to work.  The relevant files are included below.

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Rspec.configure do |config|
    config.include Capybara::DSL
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
    config.app = "Sample App"
end
```

**features/static_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Static pages" do

    feature "Home page" do

        it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do

            visit '/static_pages/home'
            expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')

        end
    end
end
```

And the relevant error message that is throwing me for a loop:

```
Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
NoMethodError:
    undefined method `call' for "Sample App":String
#./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Seeing the error I have tried removing config.app from **spec_helper.rb**, but that just leads to another error.

```
Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
ArgumentError:
    rack-test requires a rack applicaiton, but none was given
#./spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Why do you have `config.app = "Sample App"` in your spec_helper? And shouldn't it be `SampleApp`, instead of `"Sample App"`?

Comment: When I do not include config.app, I get a different error that still prevents the test from executing.

Comment: Did you try changing `"Sample App"` to just `SampleApp`?

Comment: I have and I get an uninitialised constant error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the reasoning is, but after doing more research to fix this issue in **spec/features/static_pages_spec.rb** I needed to change `require 'spec_helper'` to `require 'rails_helper'`.

Comment: FWIW this change appeared in RSpec version 3--the Rails-specific configuration was moved out of the generic spec_helper.rb into rails_helper.rb